# Springboot openID doesnt redirect after Instagram login

Tags: spring-boot, instagram, openid

I want to test openID with sprinboot and instagram. After setting up my app in instagram and fill website URL and valid redirect URL, server return OAuthException 400 and message: Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI. I use springboot + security:

my application.properties file looks like:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=MYID
security.oauth2.client.client-secret= MYSECRET

security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/selfl
```

and in my security file I have:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test2").authenticated();

}
```

my second endpoint works fine, but when I go to localhost:8080/test2, I got form to log in through Instagram, but after submit I got error. In instagram manage client my website URL is https://localhost:8080/ and valid redirect URL: https://localhost:8080/login

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue until I realized that I had registered the Redirect URI as https://localhost:8080/login/ while the `redirect_uri` passed as query parameter 
 in the authorize request was https://localhost:8080/login. Notice the missing trailing `/` in the `redirect_uri`.

This might not be the exact problem you're facing, and if it's not I would start by using the dev tool (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) of your browser and follow the flow from https://localhost:8080/test2 to the Instagram login and verify that the registered Redirect URI connected to the Client is exactly the same as the `redirect_uri` request parameter.